# Autocad 2012 undefined group code 10 for object on line 18?

Tags: autocad, dxf

I am working on creating a DXF file which results in a ellipse for Autocad 2012.
ellipse.dxf file is as follows.

```
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
0
ELLIPSE
5
2C
100
AcDbEntity
8
0
62
2
100
AcDbEllipse
10
2.456341489793
20
1.0357141474129
30
0.0
11
3.39798382641241
21
0.0
31
0.0
210
0.0
220
0.0
230
1.0
40
0.1413778446865976
41
0.0
42
6.283185307179586
0
ENDSEC
0
EOF
```

and the autocad is showing the following error :"Autocad 2012 undefined group code 10 for object on line 18".
Its getting hard for me to figure what is wrong with the group code 10 as it represents the x-axis first point. If I delete the group code 10 and  2.456341489793 it is than showing the same for groupcode 20.

Answer (score 1):

Your group codes are not formatted correctly.  All group codes are 3 characters in length.  If there are not 3 digits in your group code, then the code must have enough leading spaces to make up 3 characters.   As an example:  group code 10 must actually be written to the dxf file as " 10" (without the quotes).

The leading spaces are a key part of the group code.  This helps to differentiate between a group code and data.

So if group code 10 has a value of 10, the leading spaces in the group code allow the dxf interpreter to differentiate between them.

**EDIT**

Corrected group code length from 4 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

You created a minimal DXF with only the ENTITIES sections. When you open this DXF file in AutoCAD, AutoCAD expects a DXF R12 file, and DXF R12 does not support the ELLIPSE entity, which was introduced with DXF R13/14. AutoCAD should better complain about the ELLIPSE entity and not about the group code 10. This minimal DXF with just a CIRCLE entity works:

```
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
0
CIRCLE
8
Layer_is_a_required_tag
10
0.0
20
0.0
40
1.5
0
ENDSEC
0
EOF
```

@Stewbob: Leading spaces to group codes are a convention by AutoCAD but not mandatory